# jquery mobile navbar refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile navbar in my mobile application and for the first time I have ui-active for the first tab and it is active.Now if I select the second tab and then go back to the previous page and come to this page the selected tab is one but the content displayed was second tab's content. How to resolve this . Below is my HTML code

```
 <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">

                    <div data-role="navbar" id="navbar1">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" data-ajax="false" href="#one">MapView</a>
                            </li> 
                            <li>
                                <a data-ajax="false" href="#two">Available Seats</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div> 
<div class="ui-body-d ui-content" id="two">
<p>in second tab</p>
</div>
 <div id="one"> 
<p>in first tab</p>
</div>
</div>
```

is there anyway to refresh the navbar whenever it comes visible.

Answer (score 0):

This worked :)

```
$(document).on("pagecreate",function(){
    $( '#tabs #navbar1 li a' ).on( 'click', function(){
        $( '#tabs #navbar1 li a' ).removeClass( 'ui-state-persist' );
        $(this).addClass( 'ui-state-persist' );
    } );
});
```

Comment: I have sorted this out by emptying the tabs and reloading the elements again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#tabs" ).empty();
$("#tabs").append('my html elements');
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "refresh" );
```

doing this way solved the issue

Comment: Here you create the complete tab again and again. My solution just change the class of tab.

Comment: I have already tried this solution. But the problem with this is if I am in second tab and go back , when I come for next time second tab is shown . But I want the first tab to be shown when ever the user traverses to this page

Comment: Now I get what you want. It wasn't in the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#formid").trigger("create");
```

see more :-
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/faq/injected-content-is-not-enhanced.html